# Issue when using find and ls command and wildcard operators in terminal mac os x

Tags: macos, terminal, find, wildcard, ls

First of all thank you to everyone on here you have already helped me countless times. Secondly be kind I'm a total noob with these things and spent the last 2 hours trying to find an answer.

Here is my issue:

I have a large amount of media files that have automatically been resized for web (i.e. 1920x1080 resolution down to 960x540 -> 480x270 etc.). These resolutions have been added to the filename. I need to move that media library to a different web server but need to avoid to copy all these low res duplicates.

I have found this:
`sudo find DIRECTORY_PATH -name "*filename*" -delete`

which lets me specify the resolution of that specific file and then it will delete all the instances with that resolution. The issue is that specifically with image files they are all different resolutions and as they are being resized according to their original aspect ratio i would need to write this command a thousand times.

What I would like to do is specifiy a numeric range before the resolution marker i.e.:

`sudo find DIRECTORY -name "*[0-2000]x[0-2000]*" -delete`

However that doesn't seem to work. I feel the answer is very simply and I apologise for wasting your time but I can't make it work. I have tried all kinds of different variations of this.

I managed to list the files using `ls`

`ls *[0-3000]x*`

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: This is rather difficult, since the pattern-matching tools think in terms of strings, not numbers. For example, `[0-2000]` doesn't match numbers between 0 and 2000, it matches *single characters* that're either between "0" and "2" (the `0-2` part), or are "0" (the next `0`), or are "0", or are "0" (those last three `0`s are pretty redundant). So since you're deleting things using patterns that don't do what you think they do, my first question is: do you have a good backup? Because it's very likely you're going to delete at least one thing you didn't mean to.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for the super quick reply. That actually makes sense. What would you suggest might be a better solution. Also do I understand it correctly that the "find" command uses a different pattern matching tool than the "ls" command? I wonder since I managed to get the correct results with the ls command if there is an extension to that, which would delete the listed results? Also Yes I do have everything backed up locally and on a web server too. Rule number one :)

Comment: Backups good :-). As for patterns, `find` and shell wildcards wildcards both use essentially the same rules (note: in `ls *[0-3000]x*`, the expansion is done by the shell, not `ls`). But in both cases `*[0-2000]x[0-2000]*` should be equivalent to `*[0-2]x[0-2]*` (try them and compare), and both match any file where the first dimension ends with "0", "1", or "2", and the second dimension starts with "0", "1", or "2" (e.g. it'll match "20000x10000" because the "0x1" part matches, but won't match "55x31" because the "5x3" doesn't).